# How to get Activation Object from a activated object?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I have a *IMFTransform* decoder retrieved from MediaSource, and I want to know the decoder's CLSID for checking it is expected decoder.

But the `MFT_TRANSFORM_CLSID_Attribute` is only gettable from its activation object. [Transform Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371720(v=vs.85).aspx)

How do I get this attribute value or the activation object back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform don't need to expose their `CLSID` and they don't have to have them in first place. Or in some cases they migth have `CLSID`s but in the same time be unable to get instantiated directly using `CoCreateInstance`.

That is, there is no way to get transform to report its `CLSID` or recover the valid from its activation object. Transforms might, of course, implement some well known interfaces like `IPerist` and expose `CLSID` there but it is not something expected: transforms are rare in first place, then stock transforms don't offer this.